Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near '@certificateName'
I'm trying to encrypt my SQL Server database backup using certificate name in C#, but I'm encountering issues.
Here is the code that works with a hardcoded certificate name:
string encryptionClause = ", ENCRYPTION(ALGORITHM = AES_128, SERVER CERTIFICATE=MasterCertificate)";
backupCmd.CommandText += encryptionClause;

However, when I attempt to use a parameterized query like this:
string encryptionClause = ", ENCRYPTION(ALGORITHM = AES_128, SERVER CERTIFICATE=@certificateName)";
backupCmd.CommandText += encryptionClause;
backupCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@certificateName", "MasterCertificate");

It doesn't work and throws an error:

Incorrect syntax near '@certificateName'

I tried using Add() and have the same issue:
backupCmd.Parameters.Add(
    new SqlParameter("@certificateName", SqlDbType.NVarChar));
backupCmd.Parameters["@certificateName"].Value = "MasterCertificate";


Did you check if certificate name can be parametrized in the backup syntax documentation?

try setting certificate name as variable like
string certificateName = "MasterCertificate"
string encryptionClause = $", ENCRYPTION(ALGORITHM = AES_128, SERVER CERTIFICATE = [{certificateName.Replace("[", "[[")}])";
backupCmd.CommandText += encryptionClause;


Thanks, this does work, but I need to use parameters to prevent SQL Injection, and escaping strings.

@SSSSZZZZZ See edits for correct escaping
